# btouch bindings silently crashing app without output

Tags: xamarin.ios

I compiled WEPopoverController from here "for testing":

```
https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover
```

Then I created the WEPopover.dll (without error) using the following commands, added reference, and when I launch the app I get zero crash output from the Application Output frame. No way to move forward here...

btouch command:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch WEPopoverController.cs WEPopoverContainerView.cs WEPopoverParentView.cs WETouchableView.cs --outdir=gen -ns=WEPopover --unsafe --sourceonly=genfiles
```

smcs command:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs -out:WEPopover.dll `cat genfiles` -unsafe -r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll -target:library
```

mtouch arguments:

```
-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreFoundation -framework UIKit -L${ProjectDir} -lWEPopover -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libWEPopover.a"
```

You can find my working copy of WEPopover bindings forked from the monotouch-bindings project on github here:

```
https://github.com/anujb/monotouch-bindings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the static lib is not compiled for the architecture you are deploying to. For example, if your static lib is compiled for ARM and you are trying to run the app on the simulator (i386), it will just crash when the object you have bound is needed.

Check the build output for something like:

**ld: warning: ... missing required architecture ... in file.**

Comment: The build output indicates everything is successful. The Application Output indicates no issues. Even on MD stable. The statically compiled lib is a standard project which supports iPhone simulator / iPhone and ARM6 + 7

Comment: Try checking Xcode console with the device connected and the crash logs.

Comment: Had to use `lipo` to build for both arm6, arm7, and i386. Thanks!